# Add multiple recipients contact us from

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, contact-us, smtp, send-mail

I have a contact form.
The smtp module is installed on the project.
For smtp service we use smtp.gmail.com.

smtp module will collect all sendings and redirect them to the mail service, but my task is to add it to STORES> Configuration> GENERAL> Contacts> Email Options
second mail. But there was validation

[image]

If you remove the validation and paste the mail as on the screen

[image]

then when submitting the form there will be such an error `5.1.2 The recipient address <support@mage.com info@mage.com 5.1.2> is not a valid RFC-5321 address. m21sm455969lfh. 39 - gsmtp`

Answer (score 3):

You will need to extend the framework.

Each email needs to be individually added as a destination address.

I do this for CC address in this extension

https://github.com/DominicWatts/EmailCC/blob/master/Plugin/Magento/Framework/Mail/Template/TransportBuilder.php#L51

There isn't a quick and easy method I can show you

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Mail/Message.php#L118-L122

```
public function addTo($toAddress)
{
    $this->zendMessage->addTo($toAddress);
    return $this;
}
```

You'd need to adapt something like this https://github.com/DominicWatts/ContactAttachment/blob/master/Rewrite/Magento/Contact/Controller/Index/Post.php#L215

Or you can use something like this

https://www.magenticity.com/contact-inquiry-manager-magento2.html

Might be more cost effective/easier for you

**Update**

I created an extension

https://github.com/DominicWatts/ContactCc

Not as clean as I would like but you can see I build different sends based on configuration.

Comment: i should create a new module and rewrite those 3 files?

Comment: @annkarsksya check my updated answer